# printing a string like a matrix

Tags: python-3.x, list

Trying to let the user input a number, and print a table according to the square of its size. Here's an example.

```
Size--> 3
 0  1  2
 3  4  5
 6  7  8

Size--> 4
 0  1  2  3
 4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15

Size--> 6
 0  1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31 32 33 34 35

Size--> 9
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44
45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53
54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62
63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71
72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80
```

Here's is the code that i have tried.

```
length=int(input('Size--> '))
size=length*length
biglist=[]
for i in range(size):
    biglist.append(i)
biglist = [str(i) for i in biglist]
for i in range(0, len(biglist), length):
        print(' '.join(biglist[i: i+length]))
```

but instead here's what i got

```
Size--> 3
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8

Size--> 4
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11
12 13 14 15

Size--> 6
0 1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31 32 33 34 35
```

As you can see the rows are not aligned properly like the example. 
What's the simplest way of presenting it in a proper alignment? Thx :)

Comment: Instead of, biglist = [str(I) for i in biglist] you can convert the i variable to a string when you append to big list. Ie, biglist.append(str(i)). This is more efficient.

Comment: As for answering your question, try using the format method that is built in to python. There are so many resources about this, start there.

Answer (score 0):

Using .format on string with right aligning.

And *strlen* is the number of characters required for each number.

```py
length = int(input('Size--> '))
size = length*length
biglist = []
for i in range(size):
    biglist.append(i)
biglist = [str(i) for i in biglist]
strlen = len(str(length**2-1))+1
for i in range(0, len(biglist), length):
    # print(' '.join(biglist[i: i+length]))
    for x in biglist[i: i+length]:
        print(f"{x:>{strlen}}", end='')
    print()
```

Comment: Thx for the help mate ! ;)